# unable to reset the af:query panel search fields after page navigation

Tags: oracle-adf

I've created a search page using default Named Criteria. I'm able to search and reset the search fields while being on the page. If I navigate to another page without clearing the search fields, the previous values are getting stored in the fields and unable to clear the fields with the reset button.

[image]

```
<af:query id="qryId1" headerText="Search" disclosed="true"
                    value="#{bindings.ImplicitViewCriteriaQuery.queryDescriptor}"
                    model="#{bindings.ImplicitViewCriteriaQuery.queryModel}"
                    queryListener="#{bindings.ImplicitViewCriteriaQuery.processQuery}"
                    queryOperationListener="#{bindings.ImplicitViewCriteriaQuery.processQueryOperation}"
                    resultComponentId="::resId1" rows="2" maxColumns="3"
                    runQueryAutomatically="searchDependent"
                    saveResultsLayout="never" clientComponent="false"
                    contentDelivery="immediate" immediate="true"/>
```